# Signing a desktop application

Tags: desktop

I'd like to know how to have a desktop application signed as a product from my company. I'm not sure of the details.I think the process is I have to purchase a certificate from a company like verisign
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You need to sign the code with an Authenticode certificate.

Full information here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537359(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 2):

1. Apply for a SPC.
2. Verify the applicant's credentials.
3. Generate and issue the software publisher X.509 certificate.
4. Distribute signed software.

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537361(VS.85).aspx#Obtaining_Certificat)